# All elements of order $3$ in $\operatorname{GL}(3, 2)$ are conjugated.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was working on my thesis in group theory, in particular I was classifying all groups of order $24$, and this question arise spontaneously classifying semidirect product of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ with $\mathbb{Z}_3$. In fact in order to classify this groups one has to study the automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ which is isomorphic to $\operatorname{GL}(2, 3)$. I checked with GAP and the answer is positive: all elements of order $3$ in $\operatorname{GL}(3,2)$ are conjugated. I was wondering if I could prove it without GAP. I tried to use Sylow theorems in this way:

We have that $\operatorname{GL}(3, 2)$ has order $168 = 3 \times 2^3 \times 7$. So let $x$ be a element of $\operatorname{GL}(3, 2)$ with order $3$. I want to show that if $y$ is another element of $\operatorname{GL}(3, 2)$ of order $3$ then $x$ and $y$ are conjugate.
Now, the subgroups $\langle x \rangle$ and $\langle y \rangle$ are two distinct $3$-Sylow of $\operatorname{GL}(3, 2)$ so are conjugated and then exist $z$ in $\operatorname{GL}(3, 2)$ such that $\langle y \rangle = \langle x \rangle^z$. Then we have two possibilities:
$$
  y = z^{-1} x z \,,
  \quad
  y = z^{-1} x^2 z \,.
$$

In the first case we are done. But can happen that $y = z^{-1} x^2 z$. So I have to prove that $x$ and $x^2 = x^{-1}$ are conjugate.

I was thinking to take a particular $x$ of order $3$ in order to make the demonstration more easy (in fact all element in $G$ are conjugated to $x$ or $x^{-1}$ where $x$ is generic, so I can choose one).

How would you solve this problem without it?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial

Comment: It can be shown with Burnside's transfer theorem, but this is certainly overkill.

Comment: I don’t know that theorem. Anyway i’m looking for a proof as simple as possible.

Comment: This is essentially a linear algebra question. If you know the Rational Canonical Form Theorem it's obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Check that if $A\in GL_3(\Bbb{F}_2)$ has order $3$ then $\det(xI-A)=x^3-1$.

This is separable so $A$ is conjugate to the companion matrix $C=\pmatrix{0&0&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&0}$.

(take any $v\not \in \ker(A^2+A+1)\cup\ker(A-1)$ then $v,Av,A^2v$ is a basis and in this basis $A$ acts as $C$)